# Undo does not revert document contents to the state before editor.insertHtml

Tags: ckeditor

I have problems with *undo* in when writing a ckeditor plugin.
I am using `editor.insertHtml` to add a div with a certain class into the document. If I start with an empty document, undo and redo are unlit. When I have executed the command, undo will lit. If I press undo, both will be lit. The "undoing" does not revert the document contents.

Why not?

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('plugin_name',
{
  init: function(editor)
  {
    editor.ui.addButton('Button_name',
    {
      label: 'some text',
      command: 'Command_name',
      icon: this.path + 'images/icon.png'
    });

    editor.addCommand('Command_name', { canUndo: true, exec: function()
    {
      editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
      editor.insertHtml("<div contenteditable='false' class='foobar'></div>\r\n");
      editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
    }});
  }
});
```

I also do not understand why saving of snapshots is needed both before and after the insertion of html, but that is another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - `editor.insertHtml()` takes care of taking snapshots, because it's a high-level method. It may help if you stop firing `editor#saveSnapshot`.

Second thing - since your command has `canUndo` set to `true` snapshots will be recorded automatically when you execute it. So I would recommend to set it to `false` to make `editor.insertHtml()` the only one who save snapshots.

If the above won't help then you need to check what snapshots have been taken. To do this just access `editor.undoManager.snapshots`. In your case there should be two - one with the initial content and one taken after the command is executed. Unfortunately debugging undo manager is a pain in the...

> I also do not understand why saving of snapshots is needed both before and after the insertion of html, but that is another story.

It is a good question. But let's generalise it - why I need to take snapshots **before** and after changing content?

IIRC before CKEditor 4.4.3 there were two reasons, now only the second left:

- because initially snapshots stack is empty, so to record the initial content,
- to separate typed text from a change done after that.

The first was a quirky behaviour that was finally fixed few releases ago. Now the initial snapshot is taken on `editor#instanceReady`.

But the second is still true. When you start typing editor starts counting keys and once every 25 it records a snapshot. However, if e.g. you type 5 characters and then press the bold button you expect that these 5 characters were saved as a separate action, and pressing bold as a second one. That's why the bold command takes snapshot before it's executed - to record a snapshot containing this 5 new characters, and then it takes another snapshot to record insertion of the `<strong></strong>` element.

The fact is that most likely recording keystrokes could be implemented in a way that taking snapshot before an action would not be necessary. That would require taking snapshots after every character is inserted and then grouping them. It is possible, but it would be heavier.

The sad thing is that recently we needed to start taking snapshots on every key anyway to handle some tricky cases when typing and deleting text. There's no reliable way to tell on `keydown` whether a character will be inserted/removed and good undo manager should separate typing from deleting. So we need to know what the content was after the previous character insertion in case of a following <kbd>backspace</kbd>/<kbd>delete</kbd> press and vice versa.

In other words - perhaps all this could be simplified today, after we did the recent changes to the undo manager. But one is for sure - implementing a good undo manager (especially in situation when you don't control character insertion) is extremely tricky and few do it right.

PS. `"\r\n"` at the end of the HTML to be inserted makes no difference.

Comment: Setting `canUndo` to _false_ and removing those `editor.fire('saveSnapshot');`did the trick!